# Having Problems with COUNT when using HAVING condtion

Tags: mysql, sql, database

here is the simple query, that I am using (in real world I am using active record and its big query to show you, so please consider this one for now)

```
SELECT *,(id/* another big query*/) as distance FROM members having distance<=8
```

if I run the above query then its return perfect results total 5
but I run this query

```
SELECT count(*),(id/* another big query*/) as distance FROM members having distance<=8
```

and count always count all the rows of my table,i just want apply having conditions with getting counts of rows that returns in above query.

I can't remove having clause but I can change count to something else.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the second query? Mayne the GROUP BY clause will help you.

Comment: how to implement GROUP BY can you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do something like that:

```
select count (*) from
    (
    SELECT *,(id/* another big query/) as distance FROM members having distance<=8
    )
```

Comment: thats what i have found so far, but i am using active record so its hard to hack into active record lib. (Yii Active record)

Comment: Only alternative I can see at the moment is remove contents of underlyign `SELECT` and put `count (*)` there.

Answer (score 4):

You want to filter with a `WHERE` clause (which is applied *before* aggregation), instead of a `HAVING` clause (which is applied *after* aggregation):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE distance <= 8
```

Comment: but i am using a virtual column which is in processing after aggregation. so have no choice other than having

Comment: @MeghrajChoudhary: Use the definition of `distance` in the `WHERE` clause, rather than its alias.

Comment: @MeghrajChoudhary: In that case, I'm not sure that your problem makes much sense.  If `distance` is non-aggregated, its value will be indeterminate; whereas if it is aggregated, it's not possible to filter prior to grouping.  Perhaps you can show some example data and your intended results?

Answer (score 0):

> count always count all the rows of my table, I just want apply having conditions together with count

`count()` counts rows according to a `group by` clause:

```
denis=# select * from test;
 id | test 
----+------
  1 |    1
  2 |    1
  3 |    2
(3 rows)

denis=# select count(*) from test;
 count 
-------
     3
(1 row)

denis=# select count(*), test from test group by test;
 count | test 
-------+------
     2 |    1
     1 |    2
(2 rows)

denis=# select count(*), test from test group by test having count(*) = 2;
 count | test 
-------+------
     2 |    1
(1 row)
```

Comment: i know having and count works on groups, but how do i achive my result, do you have any idea

Comment: @MeghrajChoudhary: I'd suggest posting the actual query, as part or all will likely need to be rewritten. The question is too vague at the moment to give a more meaningful answer.